# Printing Linux command line history without line numbers

Tags: bash, shell

How can I print Linux command line history without including the line numbers? I want to send it all to a text file like this:

```
history >> history.txt
```

Comment: not quite what you want, but presumably you could strip out the line numbers with something like cut or awk.

Comment: On a side note, the history is already in a text file .bash_history in your home folder (at least on my ubuntu install)

Comment: @Col That's true but it won't have your most recent history in a currently active shell.

Comment: @Keith Good point, I forgot that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, the history is a feature of the shell, and doesn't really have anything to do with Linux, per se. Assuming you are using the bash shell, if you just use the history write option it doesn't add line numbers, anyway.

```
history -w history.txt
```

Will get you what you want.

Answer (score 7):

try the following if you don't want to write to a file

```
history -w /dev/stdout
```